# Best way to parse this XML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <BMC_Impact_Manager version="1.0">
 <IMPACT_EVENT>
  <EVENT>
     <date_reception>1279568162</date_reception> 
  </EVENT>
  <EVENT>
    <date_reception>1279568162</date_reception> 
  </EVENT>
  <EVENT>
    <date_reception>1279568102</date_reception> 
  </EVENT>
  <EVENT>
    <date_reception>1279567862</date_reception> 
  </EVENT>
  <EVENT>
    <date_reception>1279567836</date_reception> 
  </EVENT>
</IMPACT_EVENT>
```

We changed the XML output to look like this... so now I no longer need help... Thanks though!

Comment: Show the worst case XML.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: jQuery itself doesn't really parse any XML at all - it hands it over to the browser. Anyway, what have you tried so far?

Comment: //"searchTag" is one of the 15 types of events, and it 
//loops through the XML 15 times
$(xml).find('IMPACT_EVENT').each(function(){
  $(this).find(searchTag).each(function(){
    arrayElement[i]$(this).find('date_reception').text();
    i++;
   });
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a proper XML parser.

```
// http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp
function parseXML(text) {
    var doc;

    if(window.DOMParser) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        doc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        doc.async = "false";
        doc.loadXML(text);
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Cannot parse XML");
    }

    return doc;
}
```

Then get all date reception tag values as

```
var xml = parseXML(xmlString);
$(xml).find('date_reception').each(function() {
    console.log(this.text());
});
```

Comment: There is more than just "date_reception" though, there are 8 more tags in each event. I just put "date_reception" so the XMl would look more simple.

Comment: @Mark - Update your question with your XML and where you are stuck. It's hard to tell from your comment how to further proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of just Javascript to parse, very simple example: http://www.captain.at/howto-ajax-xml-javascript.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got the xml as a string, then it should just be:

```
var xml = ".....";
val values = $("date_reception", $(xml))
```