# How do I load xml data into some paragraph elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, tags

I hava a seperate xml document named videoCatalog.xml

I want to grab the; Title, Auther, Camera, Date, Location, Longitude and Latitude and put it into the relivant elements

These are the html elements I want to put the xml data into, they all have id's:

```
<h3 id="hTitle"></h3>
<p id="pAuther"></p>
<p id="pCamera"></p>
<p id="pDate"></p>
<p id="pLocation"></p>
<p id="pLongitude"></p>
<p id="pLatitude"></p>
```

This is my xml document:

```
<videoDetails>
<Video>
    <Title>Surfing with Sunny Garcia and Kalani Robb</Title>
    <Auther>Sunny Garcia and Kalani Robb</Auther>
    <Camera>GoPro Hero-1080p HD</Camera>
    <Date>2010</Date>
    <Location>On the Pipeline, Honolulu, Hawaii, USA</Location>
    <Longitude>21.284096</Longitude>
    <Latitude>-157.856162</Latitude>
</Video>
<Video>
    <Title>Brian Lopes downhill</Title>
    <Auther>Brian Lopes</Auther>
    <Camera>GoPro Hero-960p HD</Camera>
    <Date>2011</Date>
    <Location>Crankworks in Blackcomb, Whistler, Canada</Location>
    <Longitude>50.115486</Longitude>
    <Latitude>-122.947594</Latitude>
</Video>
<Video>
    <Title>Boat Racing Crash</Title>
    <Auther>Gavin Hurst</Auther>
    <Camera>GoPro Hero-720p HD</Camera>
    <Date>2009</Date>
    <Location>Lake Macfarlane, Yardea, Australia</Location>
    <Longitude>-32.127942</Longitude>
    <Latitude>136.76857</Latitude>
</Video>
</videoDetails>
```

Comment: How do you want it to look? Like the XML or XLST?

Comment: It's best to use jQuery. Here's a few questions that can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510995/parse-xml-response-with-jquery

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284477/best-way-to-parse-this-xml-with-jquery